# Getting bit rate or bit depth of an audio wav file

Tags: android, audiotrack, bitrate, mediaextractor, bit-depth

I am using `AudioTrack` to play a .wav audio file. Everything is fine but I for now I have hard coded the bit depth of the audio file while initializing the `AudioTrack` object in `STATIC_MODE`.

```
mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mSampleRate, mChannels,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, dataSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
```

I want to get the bit-depth/bitrate of the .wav file programmatically and then set the encoding in the `AudioTrack` object. I have tried to use `MediaExtractor` and `MediaFormat` but it gives me only the following information:

```
mediaFormat:{mime=audio/raw, durationUs=10080000, channel-count=1, channel-mask=0, sample-rate=16000}
```

In the documentation of `MediaFormat`, it says that `KEY_BIT_RATE` is **encoder-only**. Does that mean that I can only use this option while encoding raw PCM bits. If yes, what can be any other way to read the bitrate/bit-depth programmatically? I have already tried getting the information for the same file on the terminal using the `mediainfo` binary and it gives me the correct bit depth.

Comment: Got any solution?
Can you share it?

Comment: Not yet... I am still assuming that I know the bit-depth of the audio file.

Comment: So you are giving standard value like 8, 16 etc?

Comment: Yes.. for now I have done that

Answer (score 1):

You could always look at the 34th and 35th bytes of the wav file's header. [See this resource](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    MediaExtractor mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    try {
        mediaExtractor.setDataSource(path);
        return mediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(0).getInteger("bit-per-sample");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I think it should be bits-per-sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        int bitDepth;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            bitDepth = format.getInteger("pcm-encoding");
        } else{
            bitDepth = format.getInteger("bit-width");
```

and the format above android 7.0 like

```
 mime: string(audio/raw), channel-count: int32(2), sample-rate: int32(48000), pcm-encoding: int32(2)}
```

below android 7.0 like

```
mime: string(audio/raw), channel-count: int32(2), sample-rate: int32(48000), bit-width: int32(16), what: int32(1869968451)}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html#KEY_PCM_ENCODING

Comment: please use ticks (``) to surround your code. Its better to read `getInteger()` than getInteger.